# Can not access query string in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, config

For some reason I cant access the query value only for the internal rewrite in .htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

##external redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/user-profile/%1? [R=301,L]

#internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /test/user-profile.php?id=$3 [L]
```

Here is the entire htaccess file. Its redirecting the url perfectly, just cant get the id value by itself? Thank you

Comment: What URLs are you requesting? And what is the expected URL target?

Comment: requesting `www.example.com/test/user-profile?id=1` then I want the url to be shown to user as `www.example.com/test/user-profile/1` and then still have ability to pull the id value through PHP

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `id=` in your rewrite, and you are redirecting the 2nd (`/test/user-profile.php?id=N`) to the first (`/test/user-profile/N`)

Change the first:

```
##external redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/user-profile\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^ /test/user-profile/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So this does grab the query variable, but now it wont redirect the URL to `/test/user-profile/3`

Comment: That don't change correct rewrite, only with user-profile.php

Comment: So im attempting to rewrite `www.example.com/test/user-profile?id=3` into `www.example.com/test/user-profile/3` with the also the ability to use `GET['id']`. Are you able to help? thank you for your time

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/user-profile.php?id=$1 [L]` keeps saying the query is `id=test/user-profile/7`

Comment: @BlakePrice Where did you get that rule from? It's not mentioned in the question, or the above answer?